# IPAD compatible site works offline

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

I have an IPAD compatible website that contains some staic html pages and some jquery animations.I need to work this site as offline from my IPAD.Any body know how i do this?I hear about jqtouch has some features like this?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
vks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a document cache manifest.

See this guide on how to create Javascript-Apps:
http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/

Pretty much everything covered in there :)